# Copy synchronized Data Extension in Exact target to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I am trying to create a copy of Synchronized Contact Data Extension (from Salesforce) into the non sync Data extension using Query.However none of the records are populated. can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

is the issue still open, because i was able to do it by creating a data extension with same columns and fetching using query from sync DE